# How to replace links in existing html document with new links?

Tags: java, html, file, parsing, jsoup

I have an HTML document which consist of multiple links, I need to change the links from this HTML document to new one.
Example: Input html document:
https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow1.com">stackoverflow1

Output html document:
stackoverflow
stackoverflow1

I am using jsoup parser to get list of all links from my document.
And i am facing difficulty in replacing links in html file.

Following is my code snippet: After running code, my test.html is not updated with new links.

```
Path path = Paths.get("test.html");
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("test.html"), "UTF-8");
        Element content = doc.getElementById("ExtractLinks");
        Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");

        for (Element link : links) {
            String linkHref = link.attr("href");
            System.out.println("URL:" + linkHref);
            String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
            fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll(linkHref, "www.google.com");
            Files.write(path, fileContent.getBytes(charset));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where do you put your link? Is it inside an anchor tag?

Comment: yes the links are inside anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? You only need JS.

```js
var anchor_tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < anchor_tags.length; i++) {
        var orig_href = anchor_tags[i].href;
        var new_href = orig_href.replace("https://","");
        var final_href = new_href.replace(".com/","");
        alert(final_href);
    }
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow1.com"></a>
```

Comment: i dont want code in javascript :( i need it in java